# Using the <legend> tag for input

Tags: html, forms, web-standards, fieldset, legend

So I've got a form, who's content will change based on a dropdown list of different reports.  So the question is, how horrible would it be to include a `select` box as the `legend` tag for the `fieldset`?

I know that technically it works, and semantically it makes sense (the actual text of the legend tag, the selected value is a caption of the contents of the fieldset).  But I can't help but feel dirty doing it.

Comment: sounds good. It's valid XHMTL and HTML5, and schematically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's semantically correct and the page HMTL validates then I don't see why not.

However, I'm sure there are other UI solutions to your problem. Perhaps using jQuery UI's tabs or something similar. http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

Comment: Tabs in this case would be a bit of overkill.